# How to group by Date Range starting from initial date

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have the following table structure

```
Key int
MemberID int
VisitDate DateTime
```

How can group all the dates falling with a given date range say 15 days..The first visit for the sameMember should be considered as the starting date.

eg

```
Key     ID     VisitDate(MM/dd/YY)
1        1      02/01/11
2        1      02/09/11
3        1      02/12/11
4        1      02/17/11
5        2      02/03/11
6        2      02/19/11
```

In this case the result should be

```
ID   StartDate      EndDate    
1    02/01/11       02/12/11    
1    02/17/11       02/17/11     
2    02/03/11       02/03/11     
2    02/19/11       02/19/11
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to do this would be to use [window aggregating](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx). Here's how:

1. Setup:

   ```
   DECLARE @data TABLE (
     [Key] int, ID int, VisitDate date
   );

   INSERT INTO @data ([Key], ID, VisitDate)
   SELECT 1, 1, '02/01/2011' UNION ALL
   SELECT 2, 1, '02/09/2011' UNION ALL
   SELECT 3, 1, '02/12/2011' UNION ALL
   SELECT 4, 1, '02/17/2011' UNION ALL
   SELECT 5, 2, '02/03/2011' UNION ALL
   SELECT 6, 2, '02/19/2011';
   ```
2. Query:

   ```
   WITH marked AS (
     SELECT
       *,
       Grp = DATEDIFF(DAY, MIN(VisitDate) OVER (PARTITION BY ID), VisitDate) / 15
     FROM @data
   )
   SELECT
     ID,
     StartDate = MIN(VisitDate),
     EndDate   = MAX(VisitDate)
   FROM marked
   GROUP BY ID, Grp
   ORDER BY ID, StartDate
   ```
3. Output:

   ```
   ID          StartDate  EndDate
   ----------- ---------- ----------
   1           2011-02-01 2011-02-12
   1           2011-02-17 2011-02-17
   2           2011-02-03 2011-02-03
   2           2011-02-19 2011-02-19
   ```

Basically, for each row, the query is calculating the difference of days between `VisitDate` and the first `VisitDate` for the same `ID` and divides it by 15. The result is then used as a grouping criterion. Note that SQL Server uses integer division when both operands of the `/` operator are integers.

Comment: Hey Andriy. that works great.!!!. a quick question.. what if I have two columns with which i need to group .then we may not be able to use partition by  right ?

Comment: @AshleyJohn: I'm not sure about what you mean, sorry. You can specify more than one column in the `PARTITION BY` clause, if that's what you are asking about, just separate them with a comma: `PARTITION BY Column1, Column2, Column3`. They can be expressions, too (like in `GROUP BY`).

Comment: oK. i had a misunderstanding. thought we could have only one column in partition by clause...Thanks for the clarification..